# Is there any way to print previous value of column and changed values in one row in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
SELECT  product_id , module_no , product_status ,
  LAG(module_no) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY module_no) AS OLD_V
FROM    product
WHERE   product_id  = '1'
ORDER BY
        module_no;
```

Need result as second table

[image]

Comment: Where's `B1` coming from?

Comment: What happened to `B2`,  `B2`, `B4` and `C1`? How did they disappear?

Comment: Only need rows where column values are getting change

Comment: What you are doing is mostly right; notice the WHERE clause in TheImpaler's answer, that is pretty much what you can add to your existing query to get the desired result. Note that the WHERE clause **must** be in an "outer" query, it can't be at the same level where you compute the LAG() values. That is because analytic functions are only evaluated at the end of the query (in the SELECT clause); you can't use the output from LAG() in a WHERE clause in the same query, because WHERE is evaluated before SELECT.

Comment: @mathguy Please go for it and write the improved answer.

Comment: I am not able to see TheImpaler's answer.

Comment: Another question, as I just noticed this. In your existing query, you filter for a single id (you have **where product_id = '1'**). If so, then what is the point of "partition by product_id" in the analytic function? And how do you expect to get rows with product_id = '2' in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the base query with you and few manipulation using mainly `case` required over it to achieve what you want.

```
select product_id
      ,case when current_module_no != prev_module_no
            then prev_module_no
       end module_no_old
      ,current_module_no module_no_new
      ,case when current_product_status != prev_product_status
            then prev_product_status
       end product_status_old
      ,current_product_status product_status_new
from
(
select  product_id
      , module_no current_module_no
      , product_status current_product_status
      , lag(module_no) over (partition by product_id order by module_no) prev_module_no
      , lag(product_status) over (partition by product_id order by module_no) prev_product_status
  from product
)
where (case when current_module_no != prev_module_no
            then prev_module_no
       end) is not null
     and (case when current_product_status != prev_product_status
            then prev_product_status
          end) is not null
order by current_module_no;
```